# Vector spaces with averaging on the basis vectors

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I was wondering if we can define an algebraic structure like a vector space but with one strange rule.  I want the basis vectors to add by averaging like this:

Given a basis of

$$B= \{ | 0 \rangle, | 1 \rangle ... \}$$

$$  | 1 \rangle + | 1 \rangle = | 1 \rangle $$

Or

$$  \alpha_1 | 1 \rangle + \alpha_2 | 1 \rangle = (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)/2 | 1 \rangle $$

Is this still a vector space?  Has anyone ever seen this before?  This is coming from the way colors add. (And discussion with my son, he says the alphas are shades)

Comment: I think what you get is an affine space, with the operation of taking the barycenter. A main difference from this to a vector space, is that the zero vector don’t play any special role (we don’t have $v+0=v$).

Comment: This addition is non-associative, and your distribution rules for scalar multiples is going to behave in unusual ways.

Comment: Can I ask a clarifying question? If you think of your color mixing example, let's write the color in RGB format like $(r, g, b)$. Then, do you want $Mix((100, 0, 0), (0, 50, 0))$ to give the color $(100, 50, 0)$, or $(50, 25, 0)$, or something else?

Comment: @Milten hi, I think it's  (100,50,0).  It's a good question though.  I have to think about that.